# HTML code doesn't render when jquery is added

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I have the following html in JSP page, for some reason if `<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#department").autocomplete("department.jsp",{minChars: 4});` is added after first `input type` the rest of fields do not appear in Internet Explorer 8, in Firefox and Chrome it does appear.

What could be the reason for this?

```
<table width="583" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>Employee No:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="employee " name="employee " size="30">          
                 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#department").autocomplete("department.jsp");
           </script></td>
      </tr>
```

the following code doesn't render in IE 8

```
      <tr>
        <td>Join Date </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" id="jdate" name="jdate" size="30"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Contracrt </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="cont" name="cont" size="30"/></td>
      </tr>         
    </table>
```

**Edit 1**

Complete HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
 <html><head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
      <f:view>
        <h:form id="employeefrm">
   <table width="583" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>Employee No:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="employee " name="employee " size="30">          
                 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#department").autocomplete("department.jsp");
           </script></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Join Date </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" id="jdate" name="jdate" size="30"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Contracrt </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="cont" name="cont" size="30"/></td>
      </tr>         
    </table>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
     </h:form>
      </f:view>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
 <html><head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>             
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>

        <form id="employeefrm" method="post" action="emp.jsp" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

    <table width="583" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Employee No:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="employee " name="employee " size="50">          
                 <script type="text/javascript">

      $("#department").autocomplete("department.jsp");

           </script></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Join Date </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" id="jdate" name="jdate" size="30"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Contracrt  </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="cont" name="cont" size="30"/></td>
      </tr>      
    </table>         
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
     <input type="hidden" name="employeefrm" value="employeefrm" /></form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the code that *doesn't* work, not the one that works.

Comment: @Juhana I have added the code which doesn't render in IE 8 in my question.

Comment: and where is the #department on you html?

Comment: No, I mean show a complete example that includes the JavaScript code that makes the fields disappear. It's probably because the HTML or JavaScript is broken, that's why a complete example is needed. For example, you don't have a closing `</script>` tag in the snippet. Even better make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem.

Comment: @Juhana I have added complete code as Edit 1 in my question.

Comment: Is that the one that works or the one that doesn't work?

Comment: @Juhana The one which doesn't work in IE8

Comment: It's not the same code you have in the question text (where's the `{minChars: 4}` part?) It would also be more useful to see the generated HTML, not the JSP code. Are there errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @Juhana Generated html code does displays other fields and there no Javascript errors.

Comment: No, I mean it would be better if you showed the generated HTML *in the question* instead of the JSP code.

Comment: @Juhana I have added generated HTML as Edit 2.

Comment: @Juhana When I view html code in browser I could see all elements in browser though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#department").autocomplete("department.jsp");});
}
```

and put it before

Comment: How would not using document ready cause for some fields to disappear?